# Cannot stub non-existent own property findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mocking, sinon

Trying to stub the findOne method of my User mongoose model but getting the error `Cannot stub non-existent own property findOne`.

I am using the `findOne` method in my connector to fetch the user and that works fine. It is only in the test it says the method doesn't exist:

I can call find one like so:

```
const user = await UserModel
        .findOne({email: email})
        .select(['hash', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email'])
```

and it returns my user with the selected attributes.

When I try override it in my test:

```
import UserModel from '../../models/user'

beforeEach(() => {

  // ...

  myStub = sinon
    .stub(UserModel.prototype, 'findOne')
    .callsFake(() => Promise.resolve(expectedUser))

})
```

Is there any reason why sinon would think my `UserModel.prototype` doesn't have the method `findOne()`?

My user model

```
import { isEmail } from 'validator';
import mongoose, { ObjectId } from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: { type : String, required : true },
    lastName: { type : String, required : true },
    email: { type: String, trim: true, lowercase: true, unique: true, required: 'Email address is required', validate: [ isEmail, 'invalid email' ] },
    hash: { type : String, required : true, select: false },
    refreshToken: { type : String, select: false },
});


// generate hash
UserSchema.methods.generateHash = (password) => bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null)

// checking if password is valid
UserSchema.methods.validPassword = (password, hash) => bcrypt.compareSync(password, hash)


export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Is `UserModel` a variable? It looks like a class. In that case you would have to write `new UserModel`. But if it's a variable and not an instance of anything, findOne is not a property of `UserModel.prototype`.

Comment: @UncreativeName I have updated my post to show my userModel. It is an instance of a mongoose model

Comment: In other test I am running, I can succesfully stub the `.save()` method of the UserModel so I am not sure what's different about the `.findOne()` method. Perhaps because I am also calling `.select()`?

Answer (score 0):

**UserModel** doesn't have **findOne** property neither as it's own property, nor in the prototype as soon as it inherits it from **Model** (mongoose.Model). 
You can access original findOne method via `UserModel.__proto__.findOne`.